# Cannot sign in to gitlab after fresh install Ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: git, gitlab

I've just installed git git-1.8.1.2 and gitlab gitlab_6.7.2-omnibus-1.ubuntu.12.04_amd64.deb on fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 lts following: 
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md#ubuntu-12-04
and:
https://www.gitlab.com/2014/03/12/packaged-gitlab-with-omnibus/

I have gitlab coming up from a browser so things are sorta working but I cannot sign in.
How do I set up an administrator sign in?

I don't have any LDAP so far and do not really want to get into that unless i have to. I have installed postfix.

It's not too late to start over, what is the best way to do a complete end to end install of git and gitlab?

What do I need to do now in order to sign into gitlab?
Thx for any insight.

Comment: Are you using the default login credentials provided by GitLab? - https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md#initial-login

Comment: Yay! That's what was missing. Thx!

Comment: Ruben, answer it please. I mean use answers instead of comments ;-)